# Go to new item route after creation in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've something like this in my route:

```
actions: {
  save(title, description) {
    const newCard = this.get('store').createRecord('card', { title, description } );
    newCard.save().then((card) => {
      // card.id contains the id of the new card
      this.transitionTo('cards.all'); // problem with this line
    });
  }
}
```

I want to go to the new card route after creating it. I can get the `id` of the new item from `card.id`. I've tried the following but of no use:

```
this.transitionTo('cards.card', card.id);
```

This throws some error since the `cards.card` route can't find the `id` in the params.

The following:

```
this.transitionTo('cards/' + card.id);
```

throws some error stating that `cards/45` route not found but if the new item is created and I can navigate to it.

I'm using Ember 2.6.1.

**EDIT**

My `router.js` file:

```
this.route('cards', function() {
  this.route('all');
  this.route('card', {path: '/:card_id'}, function() {
    this.route('edit');
  });
  this.route('new');
});
```

Comment: You should post your router.js file when asking question about routing so we know what routes are available, nesting, and that sort of thing!

Comment: makes sense. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be this:

```
this.transitionTo('cards.card', card);
```

I only needed to do this since my `card.js` was expecting params object and I was trying to pass a number:

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.find('card', params.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your router currently looks like?

```
this.route('cards', function() {
    this.route('all');
    this.route('card', {path: '/:card_id'}, function() {
    this.route('edit');
  });
  this.route('new');
});
```

If your wanting to go to the new route for a specific card then you would need to define a slug for new.  Something like

```
this.route('new', {path: /:card_id});
```

The transition in your action hash would like like this:

```
this.transitionTo('new', card.id);
```

Hopefully I'm understanding your use case correctly.

Comment: I don't think this will work. The problem is that the newly created item does not have an ID yet.

Comment: Fire up ember inspector and set a break point (i.e., debugger;) right before the transitionTo.  Then check the state of the new card you've just persisted to confirm whether you have an id or not.

Comment: i want to go to `this.route('cards.card', card.id)` after creating the new item but when i do that, it throws me this error  ```Error while processing route: cards.card.index Assertion Failed: You cannot pass undefined as id to the store's find method Error: Assertion Failed: You cannot pass undefined as id to the store's find method``` but if i do a `console.log(card.id)`, it gives me the correct `id`. also, i tried doing `this.transitionTo('cards.card', 1)` but it threw me the same error. but `cards/card/1` is present.